# Ontology for a semantic layer

Tags: tags, ontology

I would like to model a semantic layer for our application.
To do this, I am trying to use an ontology to tag my datas.
I also want to add concepts (tags too) (temperature, humidity, ...) and relations between theses concepts like that :

> tag <-- concept <-- thermal <-- temperature <-- indoor_temperature

and

> tag <-- concept <-- thermal <-- temperature <-- outdoor_temperature

Each tag have to be unique and it is a part of a large tags hierarchy containing tags's collections too (cold, hot, etc...).
Do I have to create a new "Depend_On" objectProperties with transitive characteristic to express "sub-tags" ?

How can I express the need with OWL ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you're trying to define some subclasses and instances of them.

I'd start from a well defined top class:

```
bfo:Quality <|-- thermal  // Read as thermal is a subclass of bfo:Quality
thermal <|-- temperature
hot_temperature <|-- temperature
cold_temperature <|-- temperature
```

Then your data becomes instances of these

```
hot_temperature <-- temp_reading_1 \\ Read as temp_reading_1 is an instance of hot_temperature
cold_temperature <-- temp_reading_2

// add instance data through object/data properties
temp_reading_2 hasTemperature 60K
temp_reading_2 atTime 1564221286.6531635
```

You may also need to partition your temperature class into a known number of subclasses. Check out the Pizza Spiciness Value Partition in [this guide to OWL and Protege](http://mowl-power.cs.man.ac.uk/protegeowltutorial/resources/ProtegeOWLTutorialP4_v1_3.pdf). Because it seems like you're dealing with sensor readings (temperature, humidity), you may find the [Semantic Sensor Network ontology](https://www.w3.org/TR/vocab-ssn/) useful.